# Oracle Trigger NEW.SAL havent been declared error

Tags: oracle, triggers

my problem is that I made a trigger that checks if column in SCOTT.BONUS.SALARY has been updated and calculates "howmuch" - raise and returns it. It says that NEW.SAL should be declared, but how can it be declared if its a column name... ?

`````
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Raise 
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON SCOTT.BONUS
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.SAL > 0.1*OLD.SAL) 
DECLARE 
   howmuch number; 
BEGIN 
   howmuch := 0.1*NEW.SAL; 
   dbms_output.put_line('Bonus changed to 10% - : ' || howmuch); 
END; 
/````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:NEW` in body of trigger as following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Raise 
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE ON SCOTT.BONUS
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (NEW.SAL > 0.1*OLD.SAL) 
DECLARE 
   howmuch number; 
BEGIN 
   howmuch := 0.1 * :NEW.SAL;  -- changes here
   dbms_output.put_line('Bonus changed to 10% - : ' || howmuch); 
END; 
/
```

Cheers!!